# Ubuntu 15.10 php file cron job

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, cron

So I have a PHP file which I periodically run through cronjob on Ubuntu 12.04 by:

- `sudo crontab -e`
- `00 00 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/file.php` (To run at midnight)

It runs successfully.

Then I tried doing the same on Ubuntu 15.10 by:

- `sudo crontab -e`
- `00,30 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/----file.php` (To run every half hour)

But this time the file won't run. Even the file permissions have been set to grant the read and execute permissions. Any help on this please?

Comment: Please check that here. http://crontab.guru/#00,30_*_*_*_*

Comment: @AzfarKashif yeah, I don't know where I was going with that. Does the file not execute at all or are there errors on execution? Are there any log entries? Does it work if you run it straight of the terminal ?

Comment: It's running from the terminal. Also, the PHP file writes to a file whenever it is executed. SO the cronjob does not execute at all. Otherwise, I would get a failure log in my txt file.

Comment: Can you please read [this related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49077/why-does-cron-silently-fail-to-run-sudo-stuff-in-my-script), and see it is a related issue